# How can I time how long garbage collection is taking in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, instrumentation

I would like to time how long garbage collection is taking.

Based on these articles:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101136/Garbage-Collection-Notifications-in-NET

I've come up with the code below. Is this the correct way to time how long garbage collection is taking in C#?

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var done = false;
        var load = new List<byte[]>();

        var pollGC = new Action(() =>
        {
            // Register for a notification. 
            GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(10, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Registered for GC notification.");

            Stopwatch gcTimer = new Stopwatch();

            while (!done)
            {
                // Check for a notification of an approaching collection.
                GCNotificationStatus s = GC.WaitForFullGCApproach();
                if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GC is about to start.");
                    load.Clear();
                    gcTimer.Restart();
                }

                // Check for a notification of a completed collection.
                s = GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
                if (s == GCNotificationStatus.Succeeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("GC has finished in {0} ms", gcTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            GC.CancelFullGCNotification();

            Console.WriteLine("Finished monitoring GC");

        });

        var doWork = new Action(() =>
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                try
                {
                    load.Add(new byte[10000]);
                }
                catch (OutOfMemoryException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Out of memory. {0}", load.Count);
                }
            }
        });

        Console.WriteLine(GCSettings.IsServerGC);

        Task.Run(pollGC);
        Task.Run(doWork);

        Console.ReadLine();
        done = true;
        GC.CancelFullGCNotification();

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know how much time is spent in GC, you can simply use the [memory performance counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided by CLR. Anything you try to reinvent will not be reliable.

You need to look for **% Time in GC** counter.

> Displays the percentage of elapsed time that was spent performing a
>   garbage collection since the last garbage collection cycle. This
>   counter usually indicates the work done by the garbage collector to
>   collect and compact memory on behalf of the application. This counter
>   is updated only at the end of every garbage collection. This counter
>   is not an average; its value reflects the last observed value.

Comment: I'm already collecting this data...but (unless I'm missing something) they do not say how long GC took.

Comment: @Darragh What do they say then?

Comment: When garbage collection runs, it presumably takes some amount of time? I'd like to know what that amount of time is.

Comment: @Darragh That's what the performance counter "% Time in GC" says. It will give you the time in percentage. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maoni/archive/2004/06/03/148029.aspx) may get you some idea

Comment: That article describes the % Time in GC counter as "the percentage of the time spent in GC since the end of the last GC". How is that the same thing as the time taken for the garbage collection to run? I want a value measured in units of time.